# lids popped loudly second day

Tags: jam

I pushed the dimple down after taking jars out of water bath.  Some popped after that and the second day I heard many very loud pops.  Are they sealed and is the jam safe?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't press down in the lids when they come out of the bath although I must admit that sometimes the temptation is overwhelming.

As the bottles cool the resultant vacuum will pull the lids with a loud pop. It is obvious which bottles didn't seal. Pushing the lids may cause them to stay depressed even if the bottle didn't fully seal.

It should not take until the next day for the pop to happen. It generally happens within an hour or so.

Take the rings off your bottles and gently pull on the lid. If they are well sealed there is no risk of the lid coming off. If the lid does come off you can refrigerate and eat right away or check your headspace, clean the rim,  and try to process with a new lid.

After one day your jam is fine even if it didn't seal. It has too much sugar to grow anything but mold and not enough time for that, especially if the lids were not removed.